# Rewrite catalog to domain without changing URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, dns

I need to transfer URL from blog.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/blog but I don't have any experiences with mod rewrite.

The blog is on Wordpress with multisite (a was add a new site).

1. Website mydomain.com is in dir `.\mysite\`
2. Blog is in dir `.\wordpress\`
3. I created subdomain blog.mydomain.com and use dir `.\wordpress\`
4. I put `.htaccess` file into dir `.\mysite\`
5. In Wordpress I created a new site for URL mysite.com\blog and used Domain Mapping plugin

I need to use blog from url mydomain.com\blog\wordpress_urls

```
# Redirect and keeep old url mydomain.com/blog/ => blog.mydomain.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://blog.mydomain.com/$1 [P]
```

This code work but it was changing ulr. I don't use HTTPS but in future I will.

Comment: How to create htacces file with rewrite rule for redirect from  mydomain.com/blog/ to blog.mydomain.com with keeping old url (mydomain.com/blog/)

Answer (score 0):

A rewrite without redirect requires enabled mod_proxy, as well as mod_rewrite and .htaccess through Apache's httpd.conf.

In your .htaccess under the DOCUMENT_ROOT, i.e. /mysite put:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if not already blog.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.mydomain\.com$ [NC] 
#rewrite request is for blog/* to blog.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ http://blog.mydomain.com/$1 [L,P,NC]
```

<sub>Note: You may want to specify your preferred [canonical URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to avoid search engine penalties for doubled content (here a [custom Wordpress sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710974/specify-custom-canonical-url-in-wordpress-post)).</sub>

Comment: It not working for me, mod_proxy is disabled :/ Server was running on IdeaWebServer (Apache fork, dedicated solution)