# How to add canonical URL to post or page from custom field?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to skip using SEO plugins for adding canonical URL to some of my posts and pages. I've thought about creating a custom field which I would then populate only when needed.

I've looked around and I've found a [very old answer on Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710974/specify-custom-canonical-url-in-wordpress-post) so I'm not sure if this is still the best way to do it.

On page [Canonical URLs In Wordpress](https://redpishi.com/wordpress-tutorials/canonical-urls-in-wordpress/) I've found the following code:

```
function canonical_r(){
if( !is_admin() ) {
$canonical_raw = (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'canonical', true));
if ($canonical_raw)  {
$canonical_url = preg_replace('/https*:\/\/|\s/', '', $canonical_raw);
?>
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo 'https://'.$canonical_url; ?>" />
<?php }} }
add_action('wp_head', 'canonical_r');
```

I guess that it could work, but it requires a child theme. I'd like to avoid that if it is possible.

Can this be done without a child theme? I used to use [Toolest plugin](https://toolset.com/documentation/programmer-reference/adding-custom-code/using-toolset-to-add-custom-code) for such things, but I don't have it available on the current project.

Comment: Hello KWriter, Tell me, are you capable to use custom plugins in this project?

Comment: I can use it, but I would rather use a purpose one. Not some big SEO plugin.